# vuejs configure webpack under loaders

Tags: webpack

I am trying to wrap my head around vuejs and one of the things I noticed in the webpack.config.js file is the following

```
test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {                
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
        }
```

Under options what does the additional loaders tag do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can customize your loaders to specify the vue-loader ..

In the Vue.js documentation, they say, "Contrary to what its name indicates, sass-loader parses SCSS syntax by default. If you actually want to use the indented SASS syntax, you have to configure vue-loader's options for sass-loader accordingly."

Check it out here: http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

Loader Config: http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/advanced.html

Hope that helps!